# Constant sample based background subtraction and interpolation

Tags: matlab, interpolation, linear-interpolation

I need your expertise for a problem. I have the following matrix with different columns.

```
Time            subsamp raw     filt_BG filter
230.5382060     1       1       1       0
230.5382176     2       1       1       0
230.5382292     1       4       0       1
230.5382407     2       4       0       1
230.5382523     1       3       0       1
230.5382639     2       3       0       1
230.5382755     1       2       1       0
230.5382870     2       2       1       0
230.5382986     1       2       0       1
230.5383102     2       2       0       1
230.5383218     1       1       0       1
230.5383333     2       1       0       1
230.5383449     1       3       1       0
230.5383565     2       3       1       0
```

It contains two different type of raw data (column 3). Each type of raw data has same no. of sub sample (column 2). The 'filt_BG' and 'filter' seprate the type of data. I try to explain the problem and required solution with the following diagram. 
[image] 
In the above diagram (leftside), raw data is plotted as a function of time. The colors are representing different windows(subsample) 'sig' and 'BG'based on 'filter' and 'filt_BG', repectively. I want to do interpolation from the window 'BG1' to the window 'BG2'(subsample to subsample), so that interpolated data can be subtracted (subsample to subsample) from 'sig1' and 'sig2'. Similarly from 'BG2' to 'BG3' interpolation and subtraction from 'sig3' and 'sig4'. This gives me 'solution1' (upper right). Now, if 'BG3' do not exsist then I want to use only 'BG2' for subtraction from 'sig3' and 'sig4'(solution2, lower right). The solution matrix would be something like below.!!! Thank you for your ideas/solution.!!! Please keep in mind that I shall have millions of data points not as simple data as described here. Also, I do not have any toolbox but only the matlab available. Any solution based on toolbox is also fine.

```
Time            subsamp solution1   solution2   
230.5382060     1       NaN         NaN
230.5382176     2       NaN         NaN
230.5382292     1       2.5         2.5
230.5382407     2       2.5         2.5
230.5382523     1       1.5         1.5
230.5382639     2       1.5         1.5
230.5382755     1       NaN         NaN
230.5382870     2       NaN         NaN
230.5382986     1       -0.5        0
230.5383102     2       -0.5        0
230.5383218     1       -1.5        -1
230.5383333     2       -1.5        -1
230.5383449     1       NaN         NaN
230.5383565     2       NaN         NaN
```

Best Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [cumsum](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cumsum.html) to compute sample and query points for the interpolation and the data can be interpolated using [interp1](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp1.html). In the case of missing BG data (raw data contain NaN) it is required to add the first and the last valid raw data to its beginning and its end so `interp1` can generate the desired extrapolations.

```
idxsig = data(:,5)==1;                         % logical index to sig
idxBG  = (data(:,4)==1) & (~isnan(data(:,3))); % logical index to BG   

f1 = find(idxBG,1,'first');
f2 = find(idxBG,1,'last');
                                               % Add the first and the last-
                                               % valid data to the beginning-
                                               % and the end of raw data to-
                                               % get valid extrapolation                           
sig = data(idxsig,3);
BG = [data(f1,3);data(idxBG,3);data(f2,3)];
idxBG =  [true ;idxBG; true];
idxsig = [false; idxsig; false];
                                               % preparing sample and query-
                                               % points for interpolation
idx_sum = cumsum(idxBG);                          
idx_sig = idx_sum(idxsig)+0.5;                 % query points
idx_BG = idx_sum(idxBG);                       % sample points
intr = sig - interp1(idx_BG, BG, idx_sig);
solution = NaN(size(idxBG));
solution(idxsig) = intr                        % reformat to the original size
solution = solution(2:end-1);

solution =

       NaN
       NaN
   2.50000
   2.50000
   1.50000
   1.50000
       NaN
       NaN
  -0.50000
  -0.50000
  -1.50000
  -1.50000
       NaN
       NaN
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It surely works for the example described above but so far not successful to get the result from bigger data with subsample size of about 200. Just a question, what is '0.5' in the 6th line of your code?

Comment: Maybe its the interpolation creating problem. Is it possible to move not via interpolation but just simple window average (BG1+BG2) / 2?

Comment: Could you provide an example that describes your data better than the current example?  I have assumed that there are equal sub sample sizes. Also 0.5 here is used to derive query points from sample points. For example if sample points are `idx_BG= [1 2 3]` and query points are `idx_sig = [1 2]` then we need to add 0.5 to each query point to get the correct interpolation `idx_sig = [1.5 2.5]`.

Comment: @ rahnema1, thank you for the reply. I understood the issue for the addition of '0.5'. Real data is similar to this but with a very big subsample. The issue is that the interpolation is only based on the first subsample point of the BG data. You got the right output because the two value in raw for the first and second subsample of 'BG1' , 'BG2' and 'BG3' are same.  But if the raw values are different then "solution = repelem(solution, size(data_matrix,1)/size(data,1))" will not work.

Comment: Change the first line of the code to `data = data_matrix;` and remove the last line. I think you will get what you want.

Comment: @ rahnema1, Thank you, it worked fine. What about solution '2'? When 'BG3' do not present then only 'BG2' should be taken for subtraction for data after 'BG2'. I mean to say that whenever one 'BG' on either side is missing then only one 'BG' can be use for subtration. How this will work?

Comment: Please provide example data

Comment: The example is already available as 'solution2' above in the question. The 'solution2' was calculated by ignoring 'BG3' and only considering 'BG2' for subtraction from the raw data comes after 'BG2'.

Comment: What do you mean by "missing BGE" ? Do you mean that the rows that contain GB3 are missing form data matrix or value of "raw" column  for example is NaN ?

Comment: I mean that the 'raw' column is NaN or do not available for BG3. so, in this case, 'raw' average for (BG2+BG3)/2  is not possible. Only BG2 is useable. Please look at the lower right section of the figure above.

Comment: Answer updated . Now solution1 and solution2 both can be computed based on the clarifications in the comment.